# assertEquals doesn't work without second parameter casting

Tags: java, junit

Folks, why I'm getting the "The method assertEquals(String, Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type DictionaryTest" error for this JUnit test?

```
@Test
 public void testEditCard() {
  Integer a = 10;
  Integer b = 12;
  Integer c = 2;
  assertEquals("test", a-b, c);
 }
```

Adding casting `assertEquals("test", (Integer)(a-b), c);` resolves the problem.

Comment: Note: The same problem and solution applies to TestNG.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because of the wonders of autoboxing and -unboxing:

```
assertEquals("test", /* this is an int */ a-b, /* this is an Integer */ c);
```

Can be evaluated as

```
assertEquals(String, long, long);
// in this case the second parameter is unboxed
// (and the first one silently casted)
```

or as

```
assertEquals(String, Object, Object);
// in this case the first parameter is boxed
```

If you declare all variables as int (not Integer), there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: I have the same problem and I need Integer(not int). Which assertequals should I use??

Answer (score 5):

It's because the compiler can't tell if you want to call `assertEquals(String, Object, Object)` or `assertEquals(String, long, long)`. Since `a-b` and `c` can be automatically coerced to `long` the compiler sees an ambiguity.

Your explicit cast tells the compiler that you want the Object version.

Note that in this case you could use `int` rather than `Integer` variables which would also fix the ambiguity.

Comment: Looking at the JUnit API it seems there is no `assertEquals(String, int, int)` which seems odd...have I missed something? Did the JUnit people really decide to force all `int` checks to be performed using `long`s? Or have I totally misread the API on http://www.junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html?

Comment: ints can be substituted for longs, just not the other way round.

Comment: Yes, I know, it just seems like a strange design decision. Integer arithmetic is often faster than long arithmetic, although I guess that will become less relevant as 32-bit systems become less common. I suppose for unit testing efficiency is not so much of an issue.

Comment: assertEquals is really weird on that one, so what is the best practice for the case of Integer ?